# VBA innertext of the selected option for HTML dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel, html-select, innertext

Is there a way to select the innertext of the selected option for a webpages dropdown list? I was trying this way but kept getting an error Object Required:

```
Dim drp As Object
Set drp = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_Dropdownlist1").selectedindex
Range("J" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = drp.innertext
```

Im trying to pull the selected options innertext from the following part of HTML sourcecode:

```
<select name="ctl05$Dropdownlist1" id="ctl05_Dropdownlist1" disabled="disabled" class="input">
<option value=""></option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">*DIRECT ISSUE</option>
<option value="2">*DIWELD</option>
<option value="3">*INACTIVE</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.selectedindex`?

The Drop down is disabled. So how do you want to get the selected item?

If you want the dropdown's inner text, try this

```
Set drp = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_Dropdownlist1")
Debug.Print drp.innertext
```

Else if you want the innertext of a particular item say, item 1, then use this

```
drp.Item(1).innertext
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

If you want to retrieve what is displayed currently in the disabled dropdown then use this

```
Set drp = IE.Document.getElementById("ctl05_Dropdownlist1")
Range("J" & (ActiveCell.Row)) = drp.Item(drp.selectedIndex).innerText
```

Comment: I was trying to copy the displayed text from the disabled boxes selected option. is this not possible if the box is disabled? My spreadsheet is for inputting a search and copying data from the results page. the results page displays some information in the disabled dropdownlist. for each new search, the result will display a different selected option in this box. Selecting a particular item isn't possible as the item number will change with each result.

Comment: It works! I added a wait for page to load before trying to pull information from the results page. It loops and worked for about 7 rows before i got that message again. I think that last problem was my macro working faster than my ie can respond. I'll slow it down some. Thank you! Once again you're a life saver!

Comment: Glad it worked out :) I was surprised because I had tested the code and it worked just fine...